# How can I disable "app is running in the background" notifications?

Tags: applications, notifications, 8.0-oreo, nokia-8

I've a notification from *Android system* that I can only snooze, not remove permanently, about an app running in the background. It's specifically about Keepass2Android:

> Keepass2Android is running in the background

I know it's running in the background so I don't need to be reminded about it constantly. Most annoying is that it takes up unnecessary space.

Is there a way to disable this notification?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am on Oreo 8.0.0 and couldn't find a setting for this so ended up using this [Hide  "running in the background" Notification](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iboalali.sysnotifsnooze)

I have several apps running in background and disabled them all using this app, as it serves no useful purpose for me to know

[Auto Notification](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autonotification) is another app that has this feature amongst other Tasker oriented features if you are interested.

I preferred the first one since I don't use Tasker

**Edit:** These are [Bye the way](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/09/android-8-0-oreo-thoroughly-reviewed/3/#h1) notifications

Answer (score 5):

Long press/Hold the ***application name*** is running in the background and toggle the switch available, like seen in the below screenshot (option is currently enabled, turn it off to disable the *running in background notification*) [image: toggle option]

Or you can go to Settings > Notifications (enable show system apps option found in  menu) > Android System > Disable *Apps running in background* (options enabled in screenshot for viability) [image: android system toggle]

Comment: There's no switch available when long pressing, and the one from your second screenshot is greyed out. What version are you on?

Comment: Android Oreo 8.0 on OnePlus 5, so the option is visible? What phone are you using?

Comment: I'm using a Nokia 8.

Comment: Hmm, Quick look around suggests the option will be available in 8.1 http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/10/26/android-8-1-feature-spotlight-can-hide-running-background-notification-without-third-party-app/ Also to note, all my other options are locked as well, so that sucks